# Java class instance from type Object can only call methods of type Object

Tags: java, object, dynamic

I implemented the code from this tutorial http://www.javablogging.com/dynamic-in-memory-compilation/comment-page-1/#comment-65105 which in a nut shell is dynamically creating a class and only saving it to memory (versus writing to a file with extension *.java* and compiling that file with extension *.class*). At the end of his `main` he instantiates the class with

```
    Object instance = fileManager.getClassLoader(null)
    .loadClass(fullName).newInstance();
    System.out.println(instance);
```

And in the file we create we defined the `toString` method so when we print out `instance` the class name is printed. But when I add methods to the class and try to call them I get the error ***method is undefined for type object***.

I know that in normal circumstances I would need to use `Object` like `Object obj = new Foo();` and then I could call Foo's members but with the code I showed above I cannot stick `new` in front of `fileManager...newInstance();`

**Conclusion:**

How can I create an instance of the DynaClass (the dynamically created class) from the tutorial and call its members.

**UPDATE:**

I'm not sure if it's possible to cast the object because we are creating the class dynamically and everything is in strings. As far as I know you cannot cast something with a string name.

Comment: Easy - cast it (if you can).

Comment: @duffymo What do you cast it to if the type doesn't exist yet? (Or do I misunderstand the purpose here?)

Comment: The type exists in memory but we do not have a name to cast it to since the name is in a string.

Comment: Did you try `Foo foo = (Foo)instance;`? If you are creating the class at runtime from source, try Javassist or Janino libraries.

Comment: There is no `Foo` to cast with. I can look into the libraries but I need to avoid libraries and use pure Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>cast it?</strike>

Foo instance= (Foo) fileManager.getClassLoader(null)
                                   .loadClass(fullName).newInstance();

**EDIT**

Oh apparently you create the class code as a String so there is nothing to link to at compile time...

So there's nothing you can do aside from calling methods via reflection I guess?

```
  Method method = instance.getClass().getMethod("myMethod", noparams);
    method.invoke(instance, null);
```

It might be better to make an interface with the methods you want to use and your dynamic class implements that interface.  Then you can cast your object to that interface.  That's usually how plug-ins work.

Comment: If you browsed over the tutorial you would see we are dynamically creating this class with strings, so I could not put a string object into a cast.

Comment: Reflection is the only way? This seems cumbersome. Shouldn't I be able to have an instance of the object and use it normally?

Comment: It is combersome but that's because Java wasn't really meant to do this.

Comment: What about implementing an interface? (see my updated answer)

Comment: And at any rate even with the code you provided using reflection still will not allow `getDeclaredMethod` to be used on `instance` because it thinks its an `Object`

Comment: I've used reflection before like you showed but I would need to say `Foo obj = new Foo();` and then I can use what you said by `Method method = foo.getDeclaredMethod...`

Comment: @codeMonkey oops wrong reflection call use `getMethod` instead

Comment: Same result. I can see in eclipse there is an error and it wants me to cast `foo.getMethod...` to `Object` which still does not solve the problem and errors.

Comment: please change `obj` in `method.invoke(obj,null);` to `method.invoke(instance);` and I will accept this as the answer. While although I'm reluctant to rely on this approach, its at least getting me to my methods, so Thank You; you did it.